Cannot enter encryption key for external usb disk with zfs encrypted pools on Ubuntu 24.04
I have 2 nvme disks
System disk:
nvme0n1          259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
|-nvme0n1p1      259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
|-nvme0n1p2      259:2    0     2G  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p3      259:3    0     8G  0 part  
| `-dm_crypt-0   252:1    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
`-nvme0n1p4      259:4    0   3.6T  0 part  
Alternate disk:
nvme1n1          259:5    0   1.8T  0 disk  
|-nvme1n1p1      259:6    0   512M  0 part  
|-nvme1n1p2      259:7    0     2G  0 part  
|-nvme1n1p3      259:8    0     2G  0 part  
|-nvme1n1p4      259:9    0   1.8T  0 part

The alternate disk is a disk with data I need and I can import it fine, but not with the encryption key
zpool list
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
altroot  1.81T   373G  1.45T        -         -     3%    20%  1.00x    ONLINE  -

when I try to enter the key interactively it generates and error
doas zfs load-key -r -L prompt altroot
Key load error: Cannot enter raw keys on the terminal
0 / 1 key(s) successfully loaded

-L prompt is what is supposed to let me do this.
doas zfs get -Ho property,value encryptionroot,keystatus altroot
encryptionroot  altroot
keystatus   unavailable  

Tells me the key status cannot be determined.
If I try to boot from that second disk while booting it halts and asks me for the encryption key interactively and that is successful but the boot fails due to an error I am trying to fix.
Added 20240829 added 1 more piece of info : I thought the terminal issue may have something to do with the runlevel: So I changed from multi-user.target : Graphical multiuser mode to rescue.target , single user mode. The same error came up.
Something screwed up on that disk and I cannot get it to boot or debug the issue so I am working from a clean Ubuntu 24.04 install to try and fix this.
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

So now I am confused. I need to decrypt the disk pool altroot and mount it to get at the data. Can anybody see a way to solve this? Thank you.
